# /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles set to -r--r--r-- but not readable by non-root user

Tags: permissions, virtualization, apparmor

I've tried to upgrade from gnome-boxes 3.28 to 3.32 but it keeps crashing because libvirtd is not able to access:

/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles

This is the terminal output:

```
user1@pts:~: gnome-boxes 
(gnome-boxes:10186): Boxes-WARNING **: 17:52:06.148: util-app.vala:178: Failed to find OS with id: 'http://redhat.com/rhel/7.6': Unknown OS ID 'http://redhat.com/rhel/7.6'

(gnome-boxes:10186): Boxes-WARNING **: 17:52:06.149: util-app.vala:178: Failed to find OS with id: 'http://redhat.com/rhel/7.6': Unknown OS ID 'http://redhat.com/rhel/7.6'
Segmentation fault
```

journalctl gives (newest line on top, oldest on bottom):

```
Sep 15 17:52:06 user1-Dell libvirtd[967]: End of file while reading data: Input/output error
Sep 15 17:52:06 user1-Dell libvirtd[10215]: End of file while reading data: Input/output error
Sep 15 17:52:06 user1-Dell kernel: gnome-boxes[10186]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fa5f804aeb1 sp 00007ffc5b9c5a78 error 4 in libosinfo-1.0.so.0.1006.0[7fa5f8047000+1
Sep 15 17:52:06 user1-Dell systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Sep 15 17:52:06 user1-Dell dbus-daemon[818]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Sep 15 17:52:05 user1-Dell libvirtd[10215]: Failed to read AppArmor profiles list '/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles': Permission denied
Sep 15 17:52:05 user1-Dell libvirtd[10215]: Failed to open file '/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles': Permission denied
Sep 15 17:52:05 user1-Dell libvirtd[10215]: Failed to read AppArmor profiles list '/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles': Permission denied
Sep 15 17:52:05 user1-Dell libvirtd[10215]: Failed to open file '/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles': Permission denied
Sep 15 17:52:05 user1-Dell libvirtd[10215]: hostname: user1-Dell
Sep 15 17:52:05 user1-Dell libvirtd[10215]: libvirt version: 5.4.0, package: 0ubuntu5 (Matthias Klose <doko@ubuntu.com> Thu, 05 Sep 2019 11:00:53 +0000)
```

As root, I checked the permissions of this files and it's -r--r--r-- and so are all it's parent directories permissions. I was able to read it's content as root but the non-wheel user trying to use cat on that file got me a permission denied error.

Is this a bug in ubuntu or am I missing something here?

Comment: What exactly is happening? Can you post any logs from the error(s)? I'm running QEMU (also using libvirtd) and the aforementioned file has the same permissions.

Comment: Ok, I will. I was just wondering. Are you able to do: cat /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles without sudo privs and get an output?

Comment: No. The file seems empty - `ls` shows a file of 0 size - but it's not.

Comment: That's the thing, it's not empty. Doing same as root gives an output. And it's set to read privs for everyone but it's not readable. I don't know if it's supposed to be like that. libvirtd (when run by my non-root user) is trying to read it and crashing when it can't.

Comment: I have no idea why this works when QEMU is running and not Gnome Boxes. All I see in the apparmor file that mentions libvirtd is this: `/usr/sbin/libvirtd (enforce)
/usr/sbin/libvirtd//qemu_bridge_helper (enforce)`

Comment: I think I might email the guy who's email came up in journalctl. He's with ubuntu and packaged libvirtd.

Comment: Hi, I'm running into a similar problem. By any chance you had Cockpit installed in your server?